# Update rendered component in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native, flux

I use ReactNative and Flux and didn't follow how to render another one component here `UserStore.addChangeListener(function(){});` instead a `Form`. So, I have a form for login, if login was successful - I need to render `NewsFeed`. How I can do it?

```
import NewsFeed from './NewsFeed';

var Form = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    UserStore.addChangeListener(function(){});
  },
  logIn: function() {
    fetch(
      // ...
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.logIn}>
          Log In
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

export default Form;
```

**UPD:**

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loggedIn: false
    }
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    UserStore.addChangeListener(function(){
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true })
    });
  },

  shouldComponentUpdate: function() {
    return component = <NewsFeed />;
  },

  render: function() {
    var component = this.state.loggedIn ? <NewsFeed /> : <AuthForm />;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        { component }
      </View>
    );
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see all of your code, something like this or close to this should work:

```
import NewsFeed from './NewsFeed';

var Form = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      loggedIn: false
    }
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    UserStore.addChangeListener((){});
  },

  logIn() {
    fetch(
      // if login is successful 
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true })
    );
  },

  render() {

   let newsfeed, button, { loggedIn } = this.state

   if(loggedIn){
     newsfeed = <NewsFeed />
   }

   if(!loggedIn) {
    button = <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.logIn}>
               Log In
             </TouchableHighlight>
   }

    return (
      <View>
        { button }
        { newsfeed }
      </View>
    );
  }
});

export default Form;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer, but `view` don't update when state change.

Comment: Try changing the listener function to this: `componentWillMount() {
    UserStore.addChangeListener(()=> {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true })
    });
  },`

Comment: The reason for the last comment is because `this` is no longer pointing to the correct context if it is used inside of a regular javascript funciton, it either must be a function using the fat arrow syntax or you can call .bind(this)